# What is the right way to wait for data in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a child-component `CheckboxListComponent` which shows a list of checkboxes. The list is populated in `ngOnInit` through a webservice-call which takes more or less time.

It also has a function `setEntryChecked` to set a specific item to checked. When `foo()` is called before the `CheckboxListComponent` has its data the call was lost or has no effect.

My solution is to wait for the result to be available with `await this.listSubject.first().toPromise()`.

Is there a better way to do this in TypeScript?

```
export class MainComponent {
  @ViewChild('checkboxList') checkboxListComponent: CheckboxListComponent;

  foo() {
    this.checkboxListComponent.setEntryChecked(..., true);
  }
 }

export class CheckboxListComponent implements OnInit  {
  list: [];

  private listSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

  async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      this.list = await this.dataService.get('url');
      this.listSubject.next(true);
    } catch (err) {
      this.listSubject.next(false);
    }

    this.listSubject = undefined;
  }

  async setEntryChecked(name: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    // wait for the list to be initialized
    if (this.listSubject) {
      await this.listSubject.first().toPromise();
    }

    // make the item checked
  }
}
```

Comment: Use resolvers. More info [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) and [here](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that should be addressed with better design rather than various Angular coding tricks.  I would recommend having the/a parent component request the data and supply it to the CheckboxListComponent via an @Input parameter.  Thus the CheckboxListComponent is ready for use as soon as the parent needs it.

This is especially true if there are multiple instances of the CheckboxListComponent component throughout your application that present the same data set.